# NeDB not saving into file with Express.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am writing a bulk import function for a password manager for myself and I have come across an issue.

There is an array of passwords to import and I'm using a `forEach()` method to iterate through each password to import.
I call the insert function and everything just stops. No error, no callback, no saving to file. Here is my code:

```js
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const { encrypt, decrypt } = require('./crypto')
const Datastore = require('nedb')

app.post('/bulkimport', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  var passwords = JSON.parse(req.body.passwords)
  var dbForUser = new Datastore('./passwords/' + req._passport.session.user + '.db')
  passwords.forEach(password => {
    function doc(code, link, name, password) {
      this.code = code
      this.link = link
      this.name = name
      this.password = password
    }
    var entry = new doc(password.name, password.url, password.username, password.password)
    console.log(entry)
      console.log('before insert') // gets logged
      dbForUser.insert(entry, function(err, doc) {
        console.log('after insert') // doesn't get logged
        if (err) return res.status(500).send()
        console.log(doc)
      })
  });
})
```

Middlewares I'm using:

```js
app.use(bodyParser.json())
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
  app.use(flash())
  app.use(session({
    secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET,
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
  }))
  app.use(passport.initialize())
  app.use(passport.session())
  app.use(methodOverride('_method'))
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems. `db.insert` according to the nedb docs takes a plain JS object, and you're calling a `res.send()` in a `forEach` (which could result in the `cannot set headers after they are sent` error. You can also skip parsing the body by using a module for that.

```
const express = require('express')
// added
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const app = express()
const { encrypt, decrypt } = require('./crypto')
const Datastore = require('nedb')

// added
app.use(bodyParser.json())

app.post('/bulkimport', checkAuthenticated, (req, res) => {
  // changed
  var passwords = req.body.passwords
  var dbForUser = new Datastore('./passwords/' + req._passport.session.user + '.db')

  // changed: forEach would just keep running, potentially causing errors
  for (let password of passwords) {
    // changed
    var entry = {
      link: password.url,
      password: password.password,
      name: password.username,
      code: password.name,
    }

    // changed to remove res.send from callback
    let e = false
    dbForUser.insert(entry, (err, doc) => {
      if (err) {
        e = true
      }
    })

    // added to exit from route if an error
    if (e) {
      res.status(500).send()
      return
    }
  }

  res.status(201).send()
})
```

EDIT:

In the chat we also discovered that `nedb` doesn't really do anything on disk unless you call it with `autoload: true` or call `loadDatabase`, which was happening on one of the databases but not the one in the Express route ([docs](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb/#creatingloading-a-database)). Adding that got things working.

Comment: When I run it, I get `SyntaxError: Identifier 'password' has already been declared`

Comment: Ah yeah, whoops. I'll edit to get rid of the destructuring assignments

Comment: Okay, new problem. The AJAX sends on the bulk import page, but body turns out undefined.

Comment: Do you have other express middlewares? bodyParser generally wants to be first in the list of middleware, otherwise previous ones can cause trouble.

Comment: Sure. I'm out of the house right now and will try it later

Comment: I have edited my question to include the middlewares I'm using, moving it to the top did not help.

Comment: Is whatever's sending the POST setting `content-type: application/json`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227304/discussion-between-icebotyt-and-zac-anger).

Comment: I have returned by the way. Can we continue?

Comment: It was fixed! [Transcript](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/227304)